# Volume UP button does not provide action when released

Tags: android

I have following code in my app. I get ACTION_DOWN as long as the volume button remains pressed, but when I release it I expect to get ACTION_UP. This does not happen. Why? Could it be a bug on my LG G2(Lollipop)? What I need is just add a listener for VolumeUp button actions.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //TODO
            Log.d(TAG,"VOL UP");
            return true;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //TODO
            Log.d(TAG,"VOL DOWN");
            return true;
        }

        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(keyCode));

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: you should use `@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {...}` to track key up

Comment: thank you @zzas11!!! It works! I thought onKeyDown() method also provides an event about button release...

Comment: You are welcome. You can refer to Android API document :  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html

Answer (score 0):

here i edit two code may be one of the work for you:

**Code 1:**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ||
        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        changeColor(keyCode);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ||
        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // do nothing                                                       

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {             
            return true;
    } else if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            return true;
    }
    return dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Did you understand the question?

Comment: @GekaK, i have understand your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to capture all the actions.

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
int action = event.getAction();
int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //TODO
        }
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //TODO
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```